# Flask Admin need HTML5 color picker field

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, color-picker, flask-admin

I'm using Flask-Admin to create views of my database tables. One of our tables has a "color" column and it's "***editable***" meaning if you click on it, you can edit the text directly and it'll update the database with AJAX. It's a text field and I'm expecting hex colors like "#3CA4FF".

I want this "***editable***" color column to have an HTML5 color picker widget to aid in color selection (i.e. `<input type="color">`).

[image: generic color picker]

Here's my Python code for:

1. The SQLAlchemy table model class
2. Custom ColorField wtforms field
3. The Flask-Admin model view class

The following works fine to add my custom ColorField to the "edit" form, but what I really want is to edit it using the `column_editable_list` option.

```py
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from wtforms.widgets.html5 import ColorInput
from wtforms.widgets import TextInput
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.fields import TextAreaField

from app import db


class UnitType(db.Model):
    """Create a SQLAlchemy model for the our manufactured units"""

    __tablename__ = "unit_types"

    id = db.Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    unit = db.Column(TEXT, unique=True, nullable=False)
    color = db.Column(TEXT, nullable=True)


class ColorField(TextAreaField):
    """Create special ColorField for the color picker"""

    # Set the widget for this custom field
    widget = ColorInput()


class UnitModelView(ModelView):
    """The Flask-Admin view for the UnitModel model class"""
    
    # List of columns to display in the view
    column_list = (
        "unit",
        "color",
    )

    # List of columns that are immediately "editable"
    # without clicking "edit" first (super-nice feature)
    column_editable_list = (
        "unit",
        # If I uncomment the following, I get an error...
        # "color",
    )

    # Specify my own custom color picker form field type
    form_overrides = {
        'color': ColorField
    }

    # form_args = {
    #     'color': {
    #         'type': "color",
    #     },
    # }

    # form_widget_args = {
    #     'color': {
    #         'type': "color",
    #     },
    # }
```

When I add the "color" field to the `column_editable_list` I get the following error:

```py
Exception: Unsupported field type: <class 'app.admin.admin.ColorField'>
```

I'm not sure what to try next...

Comment: It might be a problem with flask admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial-and-error, I've at least figured out how to add a custom select2 dropdown menu, which displays the actual color chosen to the left of the hexadecimal color value.

First create a custom widget so we don't get the following error:

```
Exception: Unsupported field type: <class 'flask_admin.model.fields.AjaxSelectField'>
```

Here's the custom widget:

```
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla.ajax import QueryAjaxModelLoader
from flask_admin.model.widgets import XEditableWidget
from wtforms.widgets import html_params
from flask_admin.helpers import get_url
from flask_admin.babel import gettext
from flask_admin._backwards import Markup
from jinja2 import escape


class CustomWidget(XEditableWidget):
    """WTForms widget that provides in-line editing for the list view"""

    def get_kwargs(self, field, kwargs):
        """Return extra kwargs based on the field type"""

        if field.type == "ColorField":
            # A select2 list of pre-defined colors, formatted to display the actual color
            kwargs["data-role"] = "x-editable-color"
            kwargs["data-type"] = "select2"
        else:
            super().get_kwargs(field, kwargs)

        return kwargs
```

Then override the `get_list_form()` method in your model view, to use your CustomWidget.

```
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView


class MyModelView(ModelView):
    """
    Customized model view for Flask-Admin page (for database tables)
    https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/#
    """

    # Custom templates to include custom JavaScript and override the {% block tail %}
    list_template = 'admin/list_custom.html'

    can_create = True
    can_edit = True

    def get_list_form(self):
        """Override this function and supply my own CustomWidget with AJAX 
        for lazy-loading dropdown options"""

        if self.form_args:
            # get only validators, other form_args can break FieldList wrapper
            validators = dict(
                (key, {'validators': value["validators"]})
                for key, value in iteritems(self.form_args)
                if value.get("validators")
            )
        else:
            validators = None

        # Here's where I supply my custom widget!
        return self.scaffold_list_form(validators=validators, widget=CustomWidget())
```

Here's my `list_custom.html` template, for overriding the `{% block tail %}` with my own `flask_admin_form.js` script for my custom widget.

```
{% extends 'admin/model/list.html' %}

{% block tail %}
    {% if filter_groups %}
      <div id="filter-groups-data" style="display:none;">{{ filter_groups|tojson|safe }}</div>
      <div id="active-filters-data" style="display:none;">{{ active_filters|tojson|safe }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <script src="{{ admin_static.url(filename='vendor/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js', v='1.3.22') }}"></script>
    {% if editable_columns %}
      <script src="{{ admin_static.url(filename='vendor/x-editable/js/bootstrap3-editable.min.js', v='1.5.1.1') }}"></script>
    {% endif %}

    <!-- Custom JavaScript -->
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/flask_admin_form.js') }}"></script>

    <script src="{{ admin_static.url(filename='admin/js/filters.js', v='1.0.0') }}"></script>

    {{ actionlib.script(_gettext('Please select at least one record.'),
                        actions,
                        actions_confirmation) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Finally, in the `flask_admin_form.js` (my replacement for the default `filename='admin/js/form.js'`), I add the following case for `x-editable-color` (my custom role). I didn't include the whole JavaScript file here for brevity. You can find it [here](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/static/admin/js/form.js) in the source code.

Notice the `select2` I added to the `$el.editable(` options:

```
...
      switch (name) {
        case "select2-ajax":
          processAjaxWidget($el, name);
          return true;

        case "x-editable":
          $el.editable({
            params: overrideXeditableParams,
            combodate: {
              // prevent minutes from showing in 5 minute increments
              minuteStep: 1,
              maxYear: 2030,
            },
          });
          return true;

        case "x-editable-color":
          // Nice pastel colors
          var colorsource = [
            {value: "#f7f7f7", text: "#f7f7f7"},
            {value: "#292b2c", text: "#292b2c"},
            {value: "#87CEEB", text: "#87CEEB"},
            {value: "#32CD32", text: "#32CD32"},
            {value: "#BA55D3", text: "#BA55D3"},
            {value: "#F08080", text: "#F08080"},
            {value: "#4682B4", text: "#4682B4"},
            {value: "#9ACD32", text: "#9ACD32"},
            {value: "#40E0D0", text: "#40E0D0"},
            {value: "#FF69B4", text: "#FF69B4"},
            {value: "#F0E68C", text: "#F0E68C"},
            {value: "#D2B48C", text: "#D2B48C"},
            {value: "#8FBC8B", text: "#8FBC8B"},
            {value: "#6495ED", text: "#6495ED"},
            {value: "#DDA0DD", text: "#DDA0DD"},
            {value: "#5F9EA0", text: "#5F9EA0"},
            {value: "#FFDAB9", text: "#FFDAB9"},
            {value: "#FFA07A", text: "#FFA07A"},
            {value: "#fce38a", text: "#fce38a"},
            {value: "#eaffd0", text: "#eaffd0"},
            {value: "#95e1d3", text: "#95e1d3"},
          ]

          var optsSelect2 = {
            placeholder: $el.attr("data-value"),
            minimumInputLength: $el.attr("data-minimum-input-length"),
            allowClear: $el.attr("data-allow-blank") == "1",
            multiple: $el.attr("data-multiple") == "1",
            // Display the actual color next to the hex value of the color
            formatResult: function (item) { return "<span style='padding-left: 20px; border-left: 20px solid " + item.text + "'>" + item.text + "</span>"; },
            formatSelection: function (item){ return item.text; },
          };
          
          $el.editable({
            // Source data for list of colors, as array of objects
            source: colorsource,
            params: overrideXeditableParams,
            // select2-specific options
            select2: optsSelect2,
          });

          return true;
...
```